# mvc route - how to customize /Products/ProductDetails/{id} to /Products/{id}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i use default route

and default url is http://example.com/Products/ProductsDetails/1

but i need change it to http://example.com/Products/1

please help me for this. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Product",
                url: "Products/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Adding the above, before the "Default" route means that, if you enter a url ending with /Products/1, you will be taken to the appropriate controller and action that you want.

Change the controller and action to suite your needs.

Comment: and action? i've productdetails action with id as string parameter. @Jason-evans